# Consulta con LEFT JOIN Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Tengo tres tablas con los siguientes datos:

**varieties**

```
------------------------------------
  id  |   variety        | status  |
------------------------------------
  1   |     VS1          |    1    |
------------------------------------
  2   |     VS2          |    1    |
------------------------------------
  3   |     VS3          |    1    |
------------------------------------
  4   |     VS4          |    1    |
------------------------------------
  5   |     VS5          |    1    |
------------------------------------
```

**units**

```
----------------------------------------------
  id   | id_grouper |   unit     |   status  |
----------------------------------------------
  1    |     13     |     1      |    1      |
----------------------------------------------
  2    |     13     |     2      |    1      |
----------------------------------------------
  3    |     13     |     3      |    1      |
----------------------------------------------
  4    |     13     |     4      |    1      |
----------------------------------------------
  5    |     13     |     5      |    1      |
----------------------------------------------
  6    |     13     |     6      |    1      |
----------------------------------------------
  7    |     13     |     7      |    1      |
----------------------------------------------
```

**sowing**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  id  |  id_grouper | id_unit  |  id_variety  | type  |  status |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  1   |       13    |    1     |      1       |   SW  |    1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  2   |       13    |    3     |      1       |   SW  |    1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  3   |       13    |    4     |      1       |   SW  |    1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  4   |       13    |    6     |      3       |   SW  |    1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  5   |       13    |    7     |      4       |   ER  |    1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

La tabla **varieties** me muestra variedades, la tabla **units** son camas y la tabla **sowing** son simebras, en esta última registra que variedades sembradas hay en cada cama y el tipo de siembra.

El tipo **SW**  siginifica que esta actualmente sembrado y **ER** que se erradicó

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar las variedades sembradas en cada cama con **type** *SW* y si una cama no esta en la tabla **sowing** o es **type** *ER* que de igual forma me la muestre la cama con variedad **NULL** de la siguiente manera:

```
----------------------------------
    unit     |       variety     |
----------------------------------
     1       |         VS1       |
---------------------------------- 
     2       |         NULL      |
---------------------------------- 
     3       |         VS1       |
---------------------------------- 
     4       |         VS1       |
---------------------------------- 
     5       |         NULL      |
---------------------------------- 
     6       |         VS3       |
---------------------------------- 
     7       |         VS4       |
----------------------------------
```

Hice la siguiente consulta usando `LEFT JOIN` pero no me funciona:

```
SELECT units.unit, varieties.variety
FROM (sowing
LEFT JOIN units ON sowing.id_unit =  units.id)
LEFT JOIN varieties ON sowing.id_variety = varieties.id
WHERE units.id_grouper = 13
AND sowing.type= 'SW'
AND sowing.status = 1
AND units.status = 1
GROUP BY units.id;
```

me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
----------------------------------
    unit     |       variety     |
----------------------------------
     1       |         VS1       |
---------------------------------- 
     3       |         VS1       |
---------------------------------- 
     4       |         VS1       |
---------------------------------- 
     6       |         VS3       |
---------------------------------- 
     7       |         VS4       |
----------------------------------
```

Soy un poco novato con este tipo de consultas, cualquier comentario o ayuda es bienvenida, espero me entiendan la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes colocar en la cláusula WHERE una columna que participa en una combinación LEFT JOIN porque "fuerza" a que la combinación requiera coincidencia.

```
SELECT u.units, v.variety
FROM       
    units u
    LEFT JOIN sowing s ON u.id = s.id_unit
       AND s.type = 'SW' AND s.status = u.status
    LEFT JOIN varieties v ON s.id_variety = v.id
WHERE u.id_grouper = 13 AND u.status = 1;
```

Evalúa si es necesario agrupar por las columnas 'u.units' y 'v.variety'.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha ayudado!

Answer (score 2):

Creo que estás filtrando demasiados datos de forma innecesaria. Por ejemplo dices:

> Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar las variedades sembradas en cada cama
>   con type SW y si una cama no esta en la tabla sowing o es type ER que
>   de igual forma me la muestre la cama con variedad NULL de la siguiente
>   manera...

Entonces, aplicas un filtro como éste:

```
AND sowing.type= 'SW'
```

¿Cómo te va a mostrar los sowing de type `ER`? Es imposible.

El resultado que quieres puedes obtenerlo simplemente con esto:

#### Consulta:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/FFDOG16106)**</kbd>

```
SELECT u.unit, v.variety
FROM       
units u
LEFT JOIN sowing s ON u.id = s.id_unit
LEFT JOIN varieties v ON s.id_variety = v.id
WHERE u.id_grouper = 13 AND u.status = 1;
```

#### Resultado:

```
unit    variety
1        VS1
2        NULL
3        VS1
4        VS1
5        NULL
6        VS3
7        VS4
```

Comment: Pienso que si se debe escribir la expresión (type = 'SW') como parte de la expresión de combinación. Al tratarse de una combinación de tipo LEFT JOIN las filas -de la tabla 'sowing'- de tipo 'ER' no producirán coincidencia y en consecuencia el valor para la columna 'variety' -en la lista de selección- resultará NULL tal como lo requiere el OP. Si mantienes tu propuesta quizá debas utilizar una instrucción de decisión como CASE para pintar NULL en caso el tipo sea 'ER', pero creo es mejor resolverlo en la expresión de combinación.

Comment: @WillamsMorales no es para nada necesario. Agrega si quieres esto al SELECT: `s.type` y verás lo que ocurre. Lo puedes probar en el [demo](http://rextester.com/FFDOG16106). El OP no quiere un valor `NULL` en el caso de `VS4`, lo cual ocurrirá si incluyes el `WHERE` relativo a `SW`. Esta consulta arroja los datos como él los quiere, según indica en el  resultado deseado.

Comment: @Cedano, ya veo donde radica el problema, hay una contradicción entre el contenido del requerimiento y el cuadro de resultados que adjunta el OP. El texto del requerimiento -que es el mismo que usted a copiado- indica textualmente "...o es type 'ER' de igual forma me la muestre la cama con variedad NULL", en consecuencia la última fila del resultado debería ser NULL. Pienso que el usuario tuvo un descuido al escribir el cuadro de resultados, si no fuese así no veo el sentido de hacer hincapié al tipo 'ER'.

Answer (score 0):

Según tu respuesta esperada, parece que la tabla principal de tu query debería ser units (dado que quieres todos los renglones de ésa tabla).

Prueba con (comenté las condiciones de *status*, porque las tablas tienen *status* 1 y tu query pedía *status* 100):

```
SELECT units.unit, varieties.variety
FROM units
LEFT JOIN sowing ON sowing.id_unit =  units.id)
LEFT JOIN varieties ON sowing.id_variety = varieties.id
WHERE units.id_grouper = 13
AND sowing.type= 'SW'
-- AND sowing.status = 100
-- AND units.status = 100
GROUP BY units.id;
```

Comment: Es con estado 1 me equivoque en esa parte! @OctavioGalindo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero me dió el mismo resultado :(!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta consulta te puede servir:

```
SELECT u.unit, ( SELECT variety FROM units
    LEFT JOIN sowing 
      ON units.id = sowing.id_unit 
    LEFT JOIN varieties 
      ON sowing.id_variety = varieties.id
    WHERE units.id_grouper = 13 AND sowing.type= 'SW'
     AND sowing.status = 1  AND units.status = 1 
     AND units.unit = u.unit
    )
FROM units as u 
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que anda por ahí

```
SELECT units.unit, varieties.variety
FROM (sowing
LEFT JOIN units ON sowing.id_unit =  units.id)
LEFT JOIN varieties ON sowing.id_variety = varieties.id
WHERE (units.id_grouper = 13
AND sowing.type= 'SW'
AND sowing.status = 1
AND units.status = 1) OR varieties.variety IS NULL
GROUP BY units.id;
```

Cambien prueba así, dejando unit como primera tabla de la cadena de `joins` que es la que tiene los datos base

```
SELECT units.unit, varieties.variety
FROM units
LEFT JOIN sowing ON units.id = sowing.id_unit
LEFT JOIN varieties ON sowing.id_variety = varieties.id
WHERE units.id_grouper = 13
AND sowing.type= 'SW'
AND sowing.status = 1
AND units.status = 1
GROUP BY units.id;
```